No bounding boxes generated for a trained YOLO NAS model using Pytorch
I have trained a YOLO NAS-s format model for image detection in a retail store using pytorch. I trained my model for approx ~8000 images, 20 epochs as per below training code. Due to memory issues my model interrupted in between but I resumed training from checkpoint file loaded epoch. But when I try to test image it simply loads image without any bounding box.
below part deals with respective YOLO image, label path declarations
from super_gradients.training.dataloaders.dataloaders import coco_detection_yolo_format_train, coco_detection_yolo_format_val
    
    BATCH_SIZE = 1
    CLASSES = ['product']
    CLASSES += [str(i) for i in range(80 - len(CLASSES))]
    
    dataset_params = {
        'data_dir': r"C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed",
        'train_images_dir':r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed\images\train',
        'train_labels_dir':r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed\labels\train',
        'val_images_dir':r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed\images\val',
        'val_labels_dir':r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed\labels\val',
        'test_images_dir':r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed\images\test',
        'test_labels_dir':r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\SKU110KDataset\SKU110K_fixed\labels\test',
        'classes': CLASSES
    }
    
    train_data = coco_detection_yolo_format_train(
        dataset_params={
            'data_dir': dataset_params['data_dir'],
            'images_dir': dataset_params['train_images_dir'],
            'labels_dir': dataset_params['train_labels_dir'],
            'classes': dataset_params['classes']
        },
        dataloader_params={
            'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,
            'num_workers': 2
        }
    )
    
    val_data = coco_detection_yolo_format_val(
        dataset_params={
            'data_dir': dataset_params['data_dir'],
            'images_dir': dataset_params['val_images_dir'],
            'labels_dir': dataset_params['val_labels_dir'],
            'classes': dataset_params['classes']
        },
        dataloader_params={
            'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,
            'num_workers': 2
        }
    )
    
    test_data = coco_detection_yolo_format_val(
        dataset_params={
            'data_dir': dataset_params['data_dir'],
            'images_dir': dataset_params['test_images_dir'],
            'labels_dir': dataset_params['test_labels_dir'],
            'classes': dataset_params['classes']
        },
        dataloader_params={
            'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,
            'num_workers': 2
        }
    )
 

below part deals with respective model, device declarations
import torch
from super_gradients.training import models
from super_gradients.training import Trainer

DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
model = models.get('yolo_nas_s', pretrained_weights="coco").to(DEVICE)
#optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
#optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
trainer = Trainer(experiment_name="SKU110K", ckpt_root_dir="./weights")

below part deals with respective parameter declarations like max epoch etc
from super_gradients.training.losses import PPYoloELoss
from super_gradients.training.metrics import DetectionMetrics_050
from super_gradients.training.models.detection_models.pp_yolo_e import PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback
    
            
    MAX_EPOCHS = 20
    
    train_params = {
        'silent_mode': False,
        "average_best_models":True,
        "warmup_mode": "linear_epoch_step",
        "warmup_initial_lr": 1e-6,
        "lr_warmup_epochs": 3,
        "initial_lr": 5e-4,
        "lr_mode": "cosine",
        "cosine_final_lr_ratio": 0.1,
        "optimizer": "Adam",
        "optimizer_params": {"weight_decay": 0.0001},
        "zero_weight_decay_on_bias_and_bn": True,
        "ema": True,
        "resume":True,
        "ema_params": {"decay": 0.9, "decay_type": "threshold"},
        "max_epochs": MAX_EPOCHS,
        "mixed_precision": True,
        "loss": PPYoloELoss(
            use_static_assigner=False,
            num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            reg_max=16
        ),
        "valid_metrics_list": [
            DetectionMetrics_050(
                score_thres=0.1,
                top_k_predictions=50,
                num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
                normalize_targets=True,
                post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                    score_threshold=0.01,
                    nms_top_k=100,
                    max_predictions=20,
                    nms_threshold=0.7
                )
            )
        ],
        "metric_to_watch": 'mAP@0.50'
    }

below is training model part and same is used during retraining by changing start epoch number
import torch
    
     # Set the desired starting epoch
    
    # Load the model with the weights from the average checkpoint file
    checkpoint_file = torch.load(r'C:\Users\Giriraj\Documents\Prernas ML Models\yolo-nas-retail-training-main\yolo-nas-retail-training-main\weights\SKU110K\average_model.pth')
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint_file['net'])
    START_EPOCH = checkpoint_file['epoch'] + 1
    max_epochs=20
    
    # Your training loop
    for epoch in range(START_EPOCH, max_epochs):
        # Train the model
            trainer.train(
            model=model,
            training_params=train_params, 
            train_loader=train_data, 
            valid_loader=val_data
        )       
        
       


I don't see anywhere where you're saving the epoch to the state dict or saving the state dict.

I was saving it before but then I could see average model checkpoint file which is always created by default and on reading it ,it showed the last epoch which was interrupted. But unfortunately when it goes inside training loop it again starts from epoch 0
